# How to maintain cursor position of radgrid after filtering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

1. I am using Radgrid for listing dtabase contents.
2. Sorting and filtering is enabled.
3. After filtering the cursor position is changing
4. I have used the code as
5. After entering a content and pressed the "Enter" key, the cursor position is changed.
6. Any tips to maintain the cursor position?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/persisting-the-selected-rows-client-side-on-sorting-paging-filtering-grouping.aspx) on Telerik's site.  This should point you in the right direction.